# How to prevent escape characters from changing the output of a randomly generated Python string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, line-breaks, password-generator

This code outputs a string of randomly generated characters. For
example: V86Ijgh(!y7l0+x

```
import string
import random

password = ''.join([random.choice(string.printable) for i in range(15)])

print(password)
```

In the case that an escape character like \n appears

```
V86Ijg\n!y7l0+x
```

and creates the output:

```
V86Ijg 
!y7l0+x
```

because it initialized a new line
rather than printing out:

```
V86Ij\n(!y7l0+x
```

like before.

What's the best way at avoiding the intended output of an escape character such as creating a new line, tab, etc, from being interpreted? I have no choice over the input because it is **randomized**. I want to know how to output the string in its raw form **without removing characters** from the original string. I want the password to be displayed as it was generated.

Comment: Pass the list of characters you deem acceptable instead of using `string.printable`.

Comment: You can use the `repr()` of a string to print our the special characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should encode your string with escape characters if you want it to keep the special characters escaped, i.e.:

```
print(password.encode("unicode_escape").decode("utf-8")) 
# on Python 2.x: print(password.encode("string_escape"))
```

Using [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) will add single quotes around your string.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your own set of characters to select frome by taking out all whitespace characters from `string.printable`, using set operators:

```
chars = ''.join(set(string.printable) - set(string.whitespace))

password = random.choice(chars)

key_length = 1
while(key_length < 15):
        password += random.choice(chars)
        key_length = key_length + 1

print(password)
```

Note that this whole loop can be replaced by the list comprehension:

```
password = ''.join([random.choice(chars) for _ in range(15)])
```

**Edit** If you want to keep the escape and whitespace characters, but just want to print the password to your console, use the [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) function:

```
print(repr(password))
```

Comment: I implemented the list comprehension and removed the while loop. However, this 'fix' doesn't **prevent** the program from interpreting an escape character and creating a new line during the output.

Comment: See my edit, I think that would take care of it if it's just about printing, I guess I misinterpreted your question